# Комментарии не показываются пользователю при добавлении в Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Обычно в вордпрессе если снять галочку с пукнта "Автор должен указать имя и E-mail", незарегистрированный пользователь при комментировании вводит только имя и комментарий, жмет отправить, и видит как его комментарий появляется с алертом "Ваш комментарий будет одоброен"(если включена модерация). НИкто кроме него этот коммент на этой странице естественно не видит, пока он не одобрен.

В версии Вордпресса 4.2.4 это не работает. Если отключить обязательный имейл и включить ручную модерацию, то незалогиненный пользователь введя имя и коммент и нажав кнопку отправки после перезагрузки страницы не видит ничего, ни коммента ни алертов.(коммент появляется в очереди на модерацию все равно) При этом, даже если имейл не обязателен, если его ввести то коммент с алертом начинает появляться. Причем вводить имейл нужно валидно, нельзя просто ввести бредотекст, тоесть вордпресс проверяет на наличие валидного имейла и только тогда показывает комментарий комментатору. КАк и где это можно отключить? чтобы обычный посетитель сайта сразу видел свой пока еще не одобренный коммент с алертом?

Comment: Обновите Wordpress до последней версии. Возможно там бага нет.

Comment: Нет, это не помогает, в версии 4.3.1 тоже самое

Comment: У меня такая же ситуация. Вы решили свой вопрос?